# Reference an ASP control inside a function or class method

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you reference an asp.net control on your page inside a function or a class.

```
private void PageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //An example control from my page is txtUserName
   ChangeText(ref txtUserName, "Hello World");
} 

private void ChangeText(ref HtmlGenericControl control, string text)
{
   control.InnerText = text;
}
```

Will this actually change the text of the txtUserName control?

I tried this and is working

```
private void PageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ChangeText(txtUserName, "Hello World");
} 

private void ChangeText(TextBox control, string text)
{
   control.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: just thought of it after writing the question, haven't tried it yet

Comment: Is this actually your `Page_Load` event in the ASPX code-behind? Is the function you're calling in the same code-behind as well? Is this for changing the `InnerText` of any control or to specifically set the `Text` property of an `<asp:textbox />` control?

Comment: you just need to give an `id` attribute to your control and you can then reference it directly by its Id ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should, assuming it's at the appropriate point in the page lifecycle, so that nothing else messes with it afterwards. (I don't know the details of ASP.NET lifecycles.

However, it's worth mentioning that there's absolutely no reason to pass it by reference here. It suggests that you don't fully understand parameter passing in .NET - I suggest you read [my article on it](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) - once you understand that (and the reference/value type distinction) all kinds of things may become easier for you.

Of course, if you've already *tried* the code given in the question and found it didn't work, please give more details. Depending on the type of `txtUserName`, it could even be that *with* `ref` it won't compile, but *without* `ref` it will just work.

Comment: I didn't know objects are passed by reference by default

Comment: @geocine: They're not. Objects aren't passed *at all*. References are passed by value though. Please read the article I linked to in the text.

Comment: @js I am currently reading your article , however checked my update post and please explain why it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, all you need to do is this:

```
private void PageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtUserName.Text = "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: I know that, I want to create a method not only to change text later but inside a class. The one above is just a direct example